# SQL set multiple columns that use multiple joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables, one for gate techs and the other where I assign those gates techs to our stores.  A single store can have multiple gate techs.  The techs all get an ID and that is how they are stored in the stores table.  An example would be GateTechA has an ID of one.  Store 5's main gate tech is 1.  When I display the information it joins the tables and gets the name, I can set one at a time but I when I try to do two, I get errors.

The code below doesn't work but I think it best describes what I'm looking to do.  In the example below, I'm setting store 31's sliding door and swing door tech.  If I just do one, it works, but when I try to do multiple I'm getting failures when I put in correlations, which I think is where I'm screwing up.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
update dbo.tblStoreTechAssignments
Set strDoorSliding = intGateKey, strDoorSwing = intGateKey
From dbo.tblGateTechs
JOIN
dbo.tblStoreTechAssignments on strGateTechName = 'Test Tech 2'
Join
dbo.tblStoreTechAssignments on strGateTechName = 'testtec3'
where intStoreNumber = 31
```

Further explaination
@GordonLinoff

Table that has the store techs on it:

```
tblStoreTechAssignments
intStoreNumber | strDoorSliding | strDoorSwing
1                   100                  102
2                   103                  105
31                  105                  106
```

Table that has the techs:

```
 tblGateTechs
    strGateTechName | intGateKey
    Test Tech 2         100
    testtec3            102
```

Run the update and tblStoreTechAsisgnements

```
intStoreNumber | strDoorSliding | strDoorSwing
31                   100              102
```

Comment: A better description would be sample data and desired results.

Comment: Define errors..

Comment: @Paparazzi "The objects "dbo.tblStoreTechAssignments" and "dbo.tblStoreTechAssignments" in the FROM clause have the same exposed names. Use correlation names to distinguish them.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Hi Gordon, i updated the question so formatting would show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this will help-

```
update dbo.tblStoreTechAssignments
Set
    strDoorSliding = (select intGateKey from dbo.tblStoreTechAssignments where strGateTechName = 'Test Tech 2'),
    strDoorSwing = (select intGateKey from dbo.tblStoreTechAssignments where strGateTechName = 'testtec3')
From dbo.tblGateTechs
where intStoreNumber = 31
```

Comment: @BhatiAshish Thank you, I didn't know that you could use parentheses to preform another task like this.  I just needed to make one change in the "from" section of the search.

`strDoorSliding = (select intGateKey from dbo.tblGateTechs where strGateTechName = 'Test Tech 2')`

I needed the gate key from the gate tech table to set it into strDoorSliding. 

Thank you very much, this was a big help.